How to limit the number of records using distinct column value count in where clause
I am trying to get 100 records when count of distinct loan ids less than 100.
Below is a prototype of query i am trying to achieve . Is there any way we can do it .
select l.loanId,b.name,b.addr,b.pin,l.updateDate
from loans l,borrower b
where (count(*)distinct l.loanId) <100


Are you trying to limit the result set to 100 rows of data, or trying to get all data for a borrower who has less than 100 loans, or something else? You've said 'count of distinct loan ids' - but you haven't shown a group-by clause so it is unclear, and you also don't have any join conditions. Please edit your question to explain more clearly, and provide sample data and current/expected results - as formatted text/tables, not as images.

You just need an analytic function to aggregate across your result set and tell you something about the whole set without reducing the actual result set itself (as group by or normal distinct would do):
select *
  from (select l.loanId,b.name,b.addr,b.pin,l.updateDate,
               count(distinct l.loanId) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) nbr_loanIds
          from loans l,borrower b
         where l.borrowerId = b.borrowerId)
 where nbr_loadIds < 100    

If you want each borrower with less than 100 loans, you can put the PK col of the borrower (here assumed to be borrowerId) in the PARTITION BY  clause.
However, the name of the table loans and the column loanId suggests that loanId might be the PK of the table, in which case there should be no need for the use of distinct at all:
select *
  from (select l.loanId,b.name,b.addr,b.pin,l.updateDate,
               count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY b.borrowerId) nbr_loans
          from loans l,borrower b
         where l.borrowerId = b.borrowerId)
 where nbr_loans < 100    

